# Declare manually the coefficients before doing an ols regression in python

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I want to run an ols regression on this type of equations: y = b0 + b1*x1 + (1 - b1) * x2 + b2 * x3.

So I need to declare manually the coefficients but I didn't find how to do it in python using the statsmodel package. Please anyone have an idea how to declare the coefficients in the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options if you want to impose the linear constraint and estimate the remaining parameters

**Rewrite formula for OLS**

```
y = b0 + b1*x1 + (1 - b1) * x2 + b2 * x3
```

as

```
y - x2 = b0 + b1*(x1 - x2) + b2 * x3
y_new = b0 + b1 * x_diff + b2 *x3
```

and estimate coefficients with OLS using the later equation.
disadvantage: `predict` returns expectation for y_new.

**GLM with offset**

```
GLM: y ~ b0 + b1*(x1 - x2) + b2 * x3, offset=x2
```

This uses `offset` with coefficient 1 in the linear function.
`predict` is for `y`, but needs offset.
Default family for GLM is Gaussian with linear link, i.e. the same as OLS.

**GLM with fit_constrained**

impose linear (actually affine) restriction that coefficients for x1 and x2 add to 1:

```
GLM.from_formula("y = x1 + x2 + x3").fit_constrained("x1 + x2 = 1")
```

(fit_constrained is not available for OLS)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For the first method, the economic theory and the macroeconomic model that I'm building doesn't accept to estimate the new y because it changes the sense of the equation economically. I didn't understand quite well the logic behind the second method, but the third I've tried it and I think it works well. Thanks again for your answer.